# Django 1.8 - How to pre-populate a Model's field based on values in that Model's QuerySet

Tags: python, django

So I have a simple Model class

*Models.py*

```
class Item(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Upon creating an new Item in the admin, I would like the **number** field to be pre-populated.

I need it to be pre-populated with an integer that is determined by the last object found with the QuerySet returned with: **Item.objects.order_by('number')**

So for example; if the highest **number** in all my Items is 24, I would like the next Item I create via the admin to have a default **number** of 25.

I know this is a fairly common problem and there are many closely related questions but I'm having real trouble finding an explicit answer for this specific situation.

I'm fairly new to Django so please don't assume any knowledge here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This requirement is only for items created through admin? Or any new item?

Comment: Django by default will add a field that will be auto-incremented when a new object is created - this is to make sure all objects have a unique identifier. Do you really need another field?

Comment: You'll need to think *very* carefully about race conditions here. What if two users add an Item at the same time?

Comment: Daniel - Good point. Thankfully I would be the only admin in the foreseeable future.

Mark Galloway - Yes only through admin for now.

Burhan Khalid - The 'number' is not strictly sequential. There could be a series of non-related random numbers to test. I just want the largest of the bunch.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [callable as your default value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default). Try this in your models.py:

```
from django.db.models import Max

def count_numbers():
    max_value = Item.objects.all().aggregate(Max('number'))
    return max_value['number__max'] + 1

class Item(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(default=count_numbers)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

---

### Edit

If you prefer to use the `order_by` clause, you can use:

```
def count_numbers():
    query = list(Item.objects.order_by('-number')[:1])
    return query[0] + 1 if query else 0
```

Not sure which one is faster though.

Comment: It could be very inefficient to pull all of the items into python to find the max.

Comment: Yep, wasn't sure of the exact Django syntax. Just edited the answer for that.

Comment: Due to the inefficiency issue, is it logical to have a "global" variable (I understand that actual global variables are a no go) that holds the highest number and use that to set the default number value? This variable could be constantly updated when each Item is saved?

Comment: The inefficiency was that, at first, I iterated over the whole queryset to apply python's `max` builtin. Doing so in the database using either `aggregate` or `order_by` is way better.

Comment: I think order_by is probably a lot slower.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can create a custom ModelAdmin and register it with the admin site:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from ..models import Item

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # Add custom logic
        largest_item = Item.objects.latest('number')
        obj.number = largest_item.number + 1

        # Delegate default behaviour to superclass
        super(ItemAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
```

Comment: It's better to use Django `F` object in cases like you describe to add value based on DB field value and not your cached (in object) value.

Comment: Actually, F doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: Actually make as this is exactly https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f

Comment: How do I use an F expression to reference the field of another row in order save this new row? I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Possible https://github.com/jpwatts/django-positions app can help in your question?

> This module provides PositionField, a model field for Django that allows instances of a model to be sorted by a user-specified position. Conceptually, the field works like a list index: when the position of one item is changed, the positions of other items in the collection are updated in response.